# Disable keyboard and trackpad for 2-in-1 laptops when semi-folded?

Tags: laptop, hardware

I have a Lenovo C940 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. When I fold my laptop over so that the keyboard is face down and the screen is angled slightly away from me, the keyboard and trackpad do not disable. They disable properly on Windows. How can I fix this?